# Angular module federation - share remote component

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation

I am using angular 11 with webpack 5 module federation. I have plans to expose component from remotes.

```
exposes: {
 "component": ".//src/app/app.component.ts"
}
```

while importing
import {component} from "mfe@component"

I am getting build error "cannot find mmodule "mfe1@component"

how to consume remotely exposed component at design time

Comment: Please share the code how you shared and how you used.

Comment: Create a module, put component inside and expose module

Answer (score 0):

The path you provided is not correct. ./ is missing in the beginning of component name. change it to as shown below.

```
exposes: {
      "./component": "./src/app/app.component.ts"
 }
```

Comment: How to consume this component in other project(shell)? I am having 3 micro frontend projects which runs independently. But i want to transfer data between these projects, how to pass?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the remote configuration in webpack.config.js in shell app ?

```
 remotes: {
     "mfe1": "http://localhost:5000/remoteEntry.js",
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work only for standalone components which has support from angular 14 onwards, on previous versions you need to expose the module